# Google Maps - How to remove lines

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-api, maps, lines

I am trying to turn off main lines (grid map) in google maps api for web, but I do not know how to do. I was trying to set borders to 0, but it still display on map.

[image: Google map - screen]

Thank you in advance for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is a bug with the latest version of Chrome. It happens on my site http://www.shortwave.am as well but only on the newest Chrome version and not Chrome 33.0.1750.154 or Firefox.